# Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3

Tags: javascript, jquery

Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3

```
at http://pmeeting.com.vn/wp-content/themes/meeting/js/boostrap/bootstrap.min.js:6:216
```

Can you help me fix error ? My website:http://pmeeting.com.vn

Comment: Uh, isn't the error clear enough ?

Comment: make sure you load jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but don't use version 3

Comment: you TRY (and fail) to load `http://pmeeting.com.vn/js/jquery1.9.1.js` - error 404 - but succeed loading `http://pmeeting.com.vn/wp-content/themes/meeting/js/jquery.min.js` - which is version 3.1.1

Comment: you mean jquery1.9.1.js = jquery.m‌​in.js ?

Comment: jquery = jquery.min.js. we can see on your website you are loading jquery-3.1.1.min.js

Comment: I use jquery.m‌​in.js =  jquery1.9.1.js and do not see error messages
but do not know if it is the best option or not.